# ExecStartPost script an infinite loop script - Is it possible to do?

Tags: systemd

I am tweaking snmpd systemd service and I want to execute a script in ExecStartPost. This will be an infinite loop script.

This script is an implementation of agentx ..

I have tried running in a normal manner with and without & , but after sometime the systemd service is timing out..

it is timing out expecting a exit status from the script is what is believe.

Is there any way to run the script in background without the systemd snmp service timing out ?

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon.
After=syslog.target network.target
[Service]
Type=notify
Environment=OPTIONS="-LS0-6d"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/snmpd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd $OPTIONS -f
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/pyagent.py
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Might have been better off on SuperUser or ServerFault but oh well

Answer (score 0):

From reading [the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html), I believe you want to keep your `&` but add `-` prefix to skip result checking:

```
ExecStartPost=-/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/pyagent.py &
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response. But I have tried doing that and still the script is timing out